# Is there a Python Regular Expression (re) character for excluding certain characters?

Tags: python, regex, character

In **Python** **Regular Expressions** (re module), is there a character to exclude a certain character?

I am asking this, because I am trying to find a regular expression pattern, that removes everything between < and > in an html code without removing everything.
Example:

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
<//html>
```

The pattern <.*> would remove everything as the < infront of html and the > behind /html would be recognized.

I don't want to type up all possible characters (basically all except < and >).

So I thought maybe there is some character which excludes a character. If this character was § for instance, maybe I could do something like <[.<§>§]*>.

Does a character like this exist?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated